# android, How to manipulate a view of a fragment by other fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

In my activity, I have two fragments. one which is at the top of activity and act as action bar. Another fragment has a view pager.

In code of Second fragment, I need to connect to Internet and download my information. First fragment has a progress bar that I want to show it while my application is getting data from server.

Is it possible to have access to a view of one fragment from another?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the solution. In my Second Fragment I did:

```
@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        Log.i(TAG, "inside onActivityCreated()");

        context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
        actionbar = (ActionBar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.ActionBar);

        if(InternetConnection.isConnectedToInternet(context))
            new myAsyncTask().execute();
        else
            Toast.makeText(context, "Internet connection not found.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

"ActionBar" is my own widget. So, I could have access to it's methodes in other part of my code.

```
public class myAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {       

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            Log.i(TAG, "myAsyncTask is about to start...");

            actionbar.showProgressBar();
        }
.
.
.
```